# Eclipse can't find a class on my classpath

Tags: eclipse

The project is a maven project.

run as maven install works

mvn install works

I have tried mvn eclipse:eclipse to  update project, I can see the jar file in my properties order and export

I have closed and reopened the project

I have deleted and re added the project

I have done a refresh

I have done a maven update project

I have cleaned the project

maven disable maven nature and then configure convert to maven project

It  builds just fine from:

The command line:

```
 mvn install
```

In eclipse run as maven install
It works in intellij idea

Answer (score 0):

For the love of all that is holy...

There was a class of the same name in this project with all lines commented out.

Deleting that source file fixed the problem.